# how to submit a form with a local list from javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, web

I have a  list that i created it in javascript and I want to send it to controller :

```
function submit1() {
    var list_id = [];

    var i;

    for(i = 0; i < @Model.Count(); i++){
        var x =docuzment.getElementsByClassName("bt1")[i].getAttribute("id");
        var xxx = document.getElementById(x).style.backgroundColor;

        if (xxx == "tomato") {
            list_id.push(x);
        }
    }

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '@Url.Action("add_invitations", "invitations")',
        data: {list_id: String},
        success: function (data) { alert("SUCCESS"); }
    });
}
```

controller :

```
public ActionResult add_invitations(List<string> ls )
{
    ViewBag.a = ls.Count();
    return View();
}
```

I always get null reference exception for ls>

Comment: i think it should be `data: {ls: list_id},`

Answer (score 1):

You are not passing the correct parameter to the `action`, it expecting to get a parameter named `ls`, but in your `data` object you are passing a parameter named `list_id`.
Try changing it to this:

```
 $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '@Url.Action("add_invitations", "invitations")',
        data: {ls: list_id},
        success: function (data) { alert("SUCCESS"); }
    });
```

Comment: still the same exception

Comment: are you sure `add_invitations` support `POST` i don't see any `[HttpPost]` attribute?

Comment: i put it get and still the same

Comment: just to be sure it's not the `for` loop issue, try to comment the `for` loop but instead of an empty array try initiate it with values: `var list_id = ['test1','test2'];`

Comment: okay if the list is not empty i get the alert success but i don't get redirect to action and stay on the same page . if the list is empty why i get an exception and not  0 for the count ?

Comment: is it possible to create a global list and add the x value to it  so i can sent it with the actionlink ??

Comment: @michel If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted. as for global variables, this is not such a good pattern.